# Using SUMIF or other formula without using helper column in EXCEL for aggregating monthly data to yearly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have an Excel workbook with two sheets, Monthly and Annual. The labels of both are same and in the same location. The columns are monthly dates ( in the format 2010-01-01, 2010-02-01, 2010-03-01 ...) in the monthly sheet and numerical years ( 2010, 2011, 2012 ...) in the annual sheet. The columns start from the same location in both sheets, but of course the Monthly has more columns than the Annual.
[image: Monthly sheet example]

[image: Annual sheet example]

I need to aggregate the data that will be in the Monthly sheet to yearly in the Annual sheet. I want to specify that adding a Year row in the Monthly sheet under the Dates row is not possible for this specific task, as per my requirements.

I have already tried and achieved the desired result by adding a helper column in the Monthly sheet, as in the image below:
[image: Monthly sheet with helper column]
[image: Annual sheet SUMIF working with helper column]

I need to do this same thing, but without having to use the helper column. I would like to avoid the use of VBA if possible and keep the solution formula based.
Other notes:

1. I need to use RC referencing and do this without helper column since this will be a sheet generated using python. We have all the code in place to do all that, but the addition of helper column is inelegant and an inefficient thing to put in place.
2. The date range of Monthly will change everytime the sheet is generated, that is why my SUMIF formula in Annual sheet image above has only Row referencing in both [range] and [sum range] of the funcion.
3. The numbers in the monthly are populated first and independently from the Annual sheet.

Comment: Have you tried combining by using sumifs() ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by combining here. I did try sumifs(). Will you please elaborate ?

Comment: sumif() takes 1 criteria, but sumifs() can have many. If you used sumifs() as you say then show how you tried it.

Comment: Formula I used in the Annual sheet Cell R3C4: =SUMIFS(MONTHLY!R4,MONTHLY!R1,ANNUAL!R1C,MONTHLY!R4C1:R9C1,ANNUAL!RC1)

This gives a #VALUE! error

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SUMPRODUCT`.

Formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($G$2:$L$7)*($F$2:$F$7=$A2)*($G$1:$L$1>=DATEVALUE("01/01/"&B$1))*($G$1:$L$1<=DATEVALUE("31/12/"&B$1)))`

Sample:

[image]